# Apply dplyr function to many files

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I'd like to loop a dplyr function through a directory of csv files. I know how to implement the command for a single file, but it would be helpful to do it for the whole directory to speed up the process, as well as create an output file that contains the summarized data for each file the function was applied to.

Essentially, each csv file contains information on species sampled in a community, across multiple host plants and years. I'd like to summarize the number of unique taxa sampled by host plant and year. I can do that using:

```
taxa <- file %>% group_by(crop, year) %>% summarise(num_taxa=n_distinct(taxon))
```

In looking at some examples on here, I know how to read in a list of files and setup the function application using lapply. However, I'm having difficulty actually embedding a working function and creation of an output file with summary data for all files. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unless you'd run into memory problems: read them all into a single file using `bind_rows(lapply(list.files(wherever), read.csv))`; use `group_by(file, crop, year) %>% do_whatever`; then write to one file.

Comment: Or, adding on to Frank's recommendation, use `do` with a write function to write out separate files.

Answer (score -2):

I do this sort of thing using `purrr::map()` over `dplyr::do()` because the `map` approach is going to replace `do` [someday](https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/719542847045636096).

```
library(tidyverse) #for dplyr, readr and purrr

summary <- map2_df(
  list_of_files,
  names(list_of_files),
  ~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
        group_by(crop, year) %>% 
        summarise(num_taxa = n_distinct(taxon)) %>%  
        mutate(id = .y))

write_csv(summary, name_of_output_file)
```

This creates your summary by mapping the `dplyr` chain to the `list_of_files` (`.x`) and `names(list_of_files)` (`.y`).  Then it binds them together and hands you back a single dataframe with your summary of all files with a handy id column to debug.  The second line writes the output out to a csv.

Comment: Hm. I like this approach and appreciate the suggestion, but am getting the following error: Error: `.y` is not a vector (NULL). I'm using the following code: `list_of_files<-list.files(".", pattern=".csv")
lst<-vector("list", length(list_of_files))

summary <- map2_df(
  lst,
  names(lst),
  ~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
        group_by(crop, year) %>% 
        summarise(num_taxa = n_distinct(taxon)) %>%
        mutate(id=.y))

write.csv(summary, file="taxa.csv")`

Comment: Just use `list_of_files` and `names(list_of_files)` you don't need the `lst`. You might want `full.names = TRUE` in `list.files()` as well.